# Variable not changing, stays at 0

Tags: javascript, html, var

I'm trying to make an incremental type game. There is this website ,[dmholley.co.uk](http://dhmholley.co.uk/incrementals.html), that gives the basic code.

**The Problem**: After buying cursors, the number of cursors does not change. It simply stays at 0.

Here is the index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="interface.css" />
    </head>

<body>
    <button onclick="cookieClick(1)">Click Me!</button>
    <br />
    Cookies: <span id="cookies">0</span>
    <br />
    <button onclick="buyCursor()">Buy Cursor </button>
    <br />
    Cursors: <span id="cursors">0</span>
    Cursor Cost: <span id="cursorCost">10</span>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

</body>
```

Heres the  main.js

```
var cookies = 0;
function cookieClick (number){
    cookies = cookies + number;
    document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = cookies;
};
var cursors = 0;
function buyCursor(){
    var cursorCost= Math.floor(10*Math.pow(1.1,cursors));
    if(cookies >= cursorCost){
        cursors = cursors + 1;
        cookies = cookies - cursorCost;
        document.getElementByID('cursors').innerHTML = cursors;
        document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;
    };
    var nextCost=Math.floor(10* Math.pow(1.1,cursors));
    document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = nextCost;
};
window.setInterval(function(){
    cookieClick(cursors);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: So debug it. Use `console.log()` to log variables at various points in your application until you discover what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to click "Click me" at least 10 times for anything to happen.

Then click  "Buy Cursor".

You will find you have an error in your code:

Note the case of the functions:

```
document.getElementByID('cursors').innerHTML = cursors;
document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;
```

Easy to fix!

Comment: aha got it, the ID and also the ' before cursors was different. Thanks